# UIViewController.view in UINavigationController size become 600x600 on iOS 9, and never changed

Tags: ios

I am using Xcode 7 GM version to test my app for iOS9.

My app works find on iOS 8 & 7, while I am testing my app on iOS9 simulator, I find my view size is not correct. I setup my view controller in xib, using autolayout and size class. I only support portrait mode, so all of my constraints are only installed in w:compact, h:regular.

After debugging using Reveal, I found that, the self.view, a UIViewController of mine, embedded in UINavigationController, is always 600*600 size and never changed after autolayout.

I see there is constraint height:600, width:600 for self.view, but I never explicitly specify them. The point is why iOS 9 is behavining like this and how do I fix it? Thanks.

The self.view is like the root view and I got no chance to set autolayout for it. No idea why it is always and never changed.

Screen shot:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, in portrait mode the size class of height is regular on any iPhone. Second, it's recommended to use size class Any as a starting point, then adjust them if you want different layout for a specific size class.